# Tailwind mobile device hidden is not working

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am trying to hide a div in mobile device, but I am not able to do that, this is my code below

```
<div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right sm:hidden">
                <p>asdasd</p>
            </div>
```

How to do this in tailwind

Answer (score 34):

Tailwind is mobile first, `sm` is 576px and above `(640px in v1)`, if you want to make it hidden below `md`, it should be just `<div class="hidden md:block">`

Comment: nice answer
<div class="hidden sm:block">
  <span>Edit</span>
</div>

Answer (score 10):

Can you try:

```html
<div class="hidden sm:block">
  <p>asdasd</p>
</div>
```

Or `sm:flex` if you want it to be flex.

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample of  with hidden on mobile:

```
<a
                href="#"
                className="hidden md:block bg-transparent py-2 px-4 border border-black rounded-md text-base font-medium text-black hover:bg-gray-100"
              >
               text
              </a>
```